# Script, using notify-send, refuses when run from Startup Applications

Tags: 12.04, scripts, startup-applications, notify-send

I want to run a python script that produces a desktop notification on start-up in Ubuntu 12.04. How can I do this?

I tried some common ways. On start-up in the "*ps aux*" command my program is listed, but no graphic interface is seen. Normal scripts run, but scripts with graphic/network interface pose a problem.

- My bash script is essentially to run a Python script that echoes a system command.
- If I manually initiate the program later, it runs fine.

---

```py
import codecs
import time
import urllib2
import os
st = "NULL"
date = time.strftime("%d-%m")
try:
    st = urllib2.urlopen("XYZ.html").read()
except:
    pass
if st != "NULL":
    st.split("XYZ")[0].split("</table>")[0]
    if date in st:
        new = st.split(date)[1:]
        events = ""
        for j in new:
            events += (j.split("</td><td>")[1].split("</td></tr>")[0] + "\n")
        events = events[:-1]
    else:
        events = "Nothing special"
    to_send = "notify-send -i A/B/C.ico " + "'Calender " + date + "-2015' '" + events +"'"
    os.system(to_send)
else:
    to_send = "notify-send -i A/B/C.ico " + "'Calender " + date + "-2015' 'Check Internet connection'"
    os.system(to_send)
exit(0)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add, what you tried to start it automatically?

Comment: Please post the command / program you run, that works "normally".

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you please help me out now? It is not an efficient code though.

Comment: Edited the title a bit, since "Graphic script" might give the wrong impression of what the question is about.  Feel free to revert if you don't agree.

Comment: Hi PS, did you manage? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Running commands on log in

This is typically one of these cases where a command breaks if it runs too soon in the log in process. The desktop is not fully loaded yet ans the command cannot be run.

Add to your Startup Applications a break before the script starts, and it will run fine:

[image]

```bsh
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python2 /path/to/script.py"
```

I tested your script both with and without the break, and indeed failed if I ran it without, but succeeded with the break.

#### A few remarks

- Be aware that if you don't use the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) you *must* precede the path to the script by `python` to run it. No matter if it is executable or not.
- On slower systems (or on a VM) , the break of 15 seconds might not be sufficient. If so try to start with a relatively long break, experimenting "down" to the limit.
- About the script; didn't really look into it, but I definitely wouldn't use `os.system` any more, use `subprocess.Popen()` instead, and oh, you can save a line by removing the first `os.system(to_send)` and un- indent the second one, since you will run the command in both cases after the `if` / `else` route . :)

Comment: @PSSrinivasan I am on my phone and quite handicapped... But you should simply use Startup Applications (from Dash)!!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. This actually means a lot to me.
Know what! I actually before posing my question here tried to put a delay thinking that the network adapter takes time to start. But the problem was I put the delay in the python program and in the "crontab -l" code. And it didn't work.

Comment: Sure.. Sorry I did not do it earlier. I am new here. Thanks again